# Continuous background audio with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play streaming audio. I'm trying to get background audio working correctly. Right now, audio continues to play when you exit the app - the lock-screen and multi-tasking bar controls even work.

When a song finishes, the app is supposed to advance to the next track and play it. It works when the app is open but not when it is in the background (a song finishes but does not advance to the next track). If a song finishes and you re-open the app, however, the next song will start up immediately.

I am currently using NSNotificationCenter to keep track of when tracks end to advance to the next track (in my app delegate). Again, it works like a charm when the app is open. Is there a better way to do this to keep audio playing after a song is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue lately. Hope the answer helps other people.

If you have a playlist for example and want to play the next song while in background mode or lock mode add this line of code on your viewDidLoad:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

This makes the app supports remote control events.